# Light background color is not showing on PC

Tags: css, wordpress, monitor, ubuntu-16.04

I am working with WordPress and When I giving the light background color

Any content then background color is not showing, But When I am using the laptop

then background color is showing.

I am using the **Ubuntu 16.04 and monitor is AOC** I did R&D but problem is same.

May be this is monitor issue, I am not sure.

Comment: You should provide a code example which reproduces your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check with inspect element in PC is that code applies to this div.
It's possible that you have poor monitor and that light color not significantly different from white color ;)
I had this issue on old monitor.